# loading a huge column using SSIS or similar technique

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, etl

I need to load a table from SQL-Server-2012 source and it has a `varchar(max)`column and that column is huge.

Total size of that column in the table is around `2.02 TB` and table size is `3.5 TB`. 
What would be the best approach to load such a table having such a big column? I have to do an initial load after that daily incremental load.

Thanks,

Comment: Ignore the size of the column and just do it.

Comment: Are the source and target databases on the same server?

Comment: No they are in different servers. Source server is SQL-2012 and target one is SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 1):

SSIS is made to work with different data sources and differences data sizes, including Big Data. And it is declared as a part of [Microsoft Big Data Solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn749804.aspx)

It is not a bad idea to Create a simple Package that read data from SQL but you can try Adding parallelism to the Read method (Reading from the same source multiple time), you can get more details in the link below:

- http://henkvandervalk.com/reading-as-fast-as-possible-from-a-table-with-ssis-part-ii

**Other useful links to improve ssis packages performance**

- https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2684/importing-sql-server-data-using-ssis--which-option-is-fastest/